# LWUIT: Changing colors on a TextField

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield

When I create a new LWUIT TextField, by default it looks like this:

[image]

It comes with that gray line underneath. How can I change the color of that line? I can change the blue text with setFgColor(), but I'd like to change that  underline as well. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change that color, I think that you must get the Nokia source code and modify the parameters in relationship with the `TextField`. Are you using Nokia SDK 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it's Nokia SDK 2.0. Is that line just a border?

Comment: You can test if it's a border calling `textField.getStyle().setBorder(Border.getEmpty())`. If the line disappears, then yes, it's a border.